# How can I create an array in C++ with its lenght equals to user input?

Tags: c++, arrays

I know I can't create arrays like this:

```
int main () {
    int length;
    std::cin >> length;
    int array [length] = {};
}
```

Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: you can do it for some compilers

Comment: it's c++, use vectors

Comment: And spellcheck your variable names!

Comment: I'm sorry !!! I'm not a native speaker ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vector

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
  int length;
  std::cin >> length;
  std::vector<int> dynamic_array(length); 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a vector:

```
std::vector<int> arr(length);
```

This will contain `length` value-initialized int's.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options. You can use an STL container such as `std::vector`:

```
int lenght;
std::cin >> length;
std::vector<int> arr(length);
```

Or you can allocate memory dynamically:

```
int* arr = new int[length];
```

Comment: By using `std::vector` in this case one does allocate memory dynamically too.

Comment: `std::array<int, length>` doesn't work. The length is a template parameter and therefore must be a compile time constant. `std::array<int, 5>` is a completely separate type from `std::array<int, 6>`. Hiding it in a `shared_ptr` doesn't make that go away (and wouldn't make much sense even if it worked).

Comment: Good point, thanks for the correction.